# Mysterious Vertical Gap Between Divs

Tags: css, html

There is a mysterious gap appearing between my header and footer. I took out the main content divs while investigating so I know it is not those to blame. Here is my website:
http://classweb2.mccombs.utexas.edu/mis333k/msbcf555/TestSite/Default.aspx

I will share the stylesheet if requested, but it is long and I feel like the solution is something obvious that I have not thought of.

What I have tried:

- Resetting the margins and padding
- Making sure no line breaks or other divs are hiding between the real divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `#header` element has `display:inline-block` applied to it. Inline-block adds visible space between elements if there is any whitespace at all - even a single space character.  I'm not why you've made it an `inline-block`, as it seems like a standard block level element.  Remove that and the space should disappear.

There are other options as well, though I think this is the simplest.  For more information on the "mysterious" spaces that `inline-blocks` creates, see here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/